# Vuex how to handle api error notification?

Tags: vue.js, redux, vuex

I started working with Vuex 2 weeks ago and I realized that Vuex is very good to handle the state of the app. But, it is difficult to handle the error of API calls. When I get data from the server, I dispatch an action. When data is successfully returned, of course, everything is fine. But when an error happens, I change state,  I don't know how to detect it through the state from Vuejs components to notify to the user. Could anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I typically have the following parts:

- A component for displaying the notification, typically an alert or a snackbar or similar, e.g. `error-notification`. I use this component on a high level,  directly below the root app component. This depends on your layout.
- A property in vuex indicating the error state, typically an error object w/ error code & message, e.g. `error`
- One mutation in the store for raising an error setting the error property, e.g. `raiseError`
- One mutation in the store for dismissing an error clearing the error property, e.g. `dismissError`

Using these, you need to:

- Display `error-notification` based on the `error` in the store: `<error-notification v-if="$store.state.error :error="$store.state.error"/>`
- When an error occurs, call `raiseError` mutation (in your API callback): `vm.$store.commit('raiseError', { code: 'ERR_FOO', msg: 'A foo error ocurred'})`
- In `error-notification`, call the `dismissError` mutation when the notification is closed.

Comment: thanks. But if I want to use Sweetalert2 library, should I watch the store's state change to show my alert?

Comment: That would be an alternative to the `error-notification` component, yes.

Answer (score 5):

You can also return a promise in your action so that if you call it from component you can catch the error there and display a notification as needed:

in your store:

```
//action
const fetch = (context) => {
    return api.fetchTodos() //api here returns a promise. You can also do new Promise(...)
        .then((response) => {
            context.commit('SET_TODOS', response);
        })

};
```

in vue component:

```
this.$store.dispatch('todos/fetch', modifiedTodo)
    .catch(error => {
        //show notification
    })
```