# Vue + Vuetify reuse snackbar / alert

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to Vue I wanted to reuse the snackbar / alert box from vuetify to each of my components. I did it by copy pasting the code for each component which makes it very messy and hard to maintain.

How do I reuse this for each of my view vue component?

Please see my example code below.

**Vue component < template >**

```
 <v-snackbar
  v-model="snackbar.appear"
  :color="snackbar.color"
  :timeout="snackbar.timeout"
  :left="snackbar.x === 'left'"
  :right="snackbar.x === 'right'"
  :top="snackbar.y === 'top'"
> 
  <v-row>
    <v-icon class="mx-2" size="18" dark>{{ snackbar.icon }}</v-icon>
    {{ snackbar.text }}
  </v-row>
  <v-btn dark text @click="snackbar.appear = false">OKAY</v-btn>
</v-snackbar>
```

**Vue component < script >**

```
snackbar: {
    appear: false,
    icon: '',
    text: '',
    color: 'success',
    timeout: 2500,
    x: 'right',
    y: 'top',
  },

axios 
.post('/api/department-objective', { corporate_objective_id, objective, description })
.then(response => {
  this.snackbar.appear = true
  this.snackbar.text = response.data.text
  this.snackbar.icon = response.data.icon
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
  this.alert = true
  this.allerror = error.response.data.errors
})
```

Answer (score 5):

I often add application wide alert messages to the root application's component, like e.g. an `App` component building up the base layout and bind it's visibility to the presence of an `error` or `notification` property in a central `vuex` store.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988261/vuex-how-to-handle-api-error-notification/52992838#52992838) for details

Comment: It seems really efficient to use vuex, though I still haven't ventured using it. Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a snackbar component , which you can import in App.vue so that it's available to the every component , you can then trigger this component using vuex store as per you're requirement.

Here's an article which I used while learning to implement the same.
[How to create a global snackbar using Nuxt, Vuetify and Vuex.](https://dev.to/stephannv/how-to-create-a-global-snackbar-using-nuxt-vuetify-and-vuex-1bda).

If you dont want to use nuxt , just refer to the article and you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a SnackBarComponent and import it on every other Component

**App.vue**

```
<template>
<SnackBarComponenent :stuffProp="yourProps" />
</template>
<script>
import SnackBarComponenent from './components/SnackBarComponent'
export default {
    components:{
        ProfileOverview
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I can't seem to access the data on the imported component from my axios this.snackbar.appear = true